# Count Customers based on item master

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count

I need you to help me on writing two queries in SQL Server 2008 that shows the following information based on item master:

1. Brand wise count on customer master plus customer who purchased the brand
2. Item Wise count of customer master plus customer who purchased the item

Here the link that shows the table information and the query which I tried.

[Click here to view the table in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fecb0/1)

```
SELECT 
   brandname,
   division,
   route,
   DivisionTotalCustomersCount = MAX(DivisionTotalCustomersCount),
   RouteTotalCustomersCount = MAX(RouteTotalCustomersCount),
   PurchasedCustomersCount = SUM(PurchasedCustomersCount) 
FROM
   (SELECT 
       i.brandname,
       c.division,
       c.route,
       DivisionTotalCustomersCount = 
          (SELECT COUNT(distinct x.CustomerID) 
           FROM CustomerMaster x 
           WHERE x.division = c.division),
       RouteTotalCustomersCount =
          (SELECT COUNT(distinct x.CustomerID) 
           FROM CustomerMaster x 
           WHERE x.Route = c.route),
       PurchasedCustomersCount = count(distinct C.CustomerID)
                                       FROM CustomerMaster c 
                                       LEFT OUTER JOIN SalesData s on c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID 
                                       right outer join ItemMaster i on s.item = i.itemcode

                                       GROUP BY i.brandname, c.division, c.route) A

    GROUP BY 
        brandname, division, route
    ORDER BY 1
```

Result Should as below

[Excelsheet](https://ethercalc.org/mmnzizii2u)

Comment: Why did your example not work?

Comment: I have few customer has not purchased any item. In my query is count of customer in the route and division is nulll which is wrong.

Comment: So do you then want to exclude brand's where nobody has purchased the brand? Otherwise you will have null for those fields because they come from the customer master table and will only be there if a customer has purchased something from that brand?

Comment: No, the report is based on brand from item master and the customer count from customer master. What I want to see is list the brands and show the available customer in my database based on route, division and also show how many customer form master list are buying these brands.

Comment: in Addition, in my report if a brand has been not purchased by any customers but still I can see how many potential customer is available.

Comment: @marc_s you have edited my query which return a wrong result. I need to see all the brands which are available in my item master

Comment: Potential customers would then just be all the customers, i.e. a distinct list of customermaster or is there a different way of calculating potential customers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56682/discussion-between-user1820065-and-tbohnen-jnr).

Comment: unfortunately my firewall blocks the chat.

Comment: any solution ? my mind is locked :((

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go reconsider the report and maybe splitting it out into multiple reports.

It does not make sense to have a route count as well as a divisional count if they are counting things at different levels of aggregation. So have a route count and division count report.

Either way, division and route is going to be null for 100PLUS because there are no customers for that brand which means there is no route or division info available.

```
--Division Count
SELECT BrandName, Division, COUNT(CustomerMaster.CustomerID) [Customer Count]
FROM ItemMaster LEFT OUTER JOIN
      SalesData ON ItemMaster.BrandName = SalesData.Brand LEFT OUTER JOIN
      CustomerMaster ON SalesData.CustomerID = CustomerMaster.CustomerID
GROUP BY BrandName, Division

--Route Count
SELECT BrandName, Route, Division, COUNT(CustomerMaster.CustomerID) [Customer Count]
FROM ItemMaster LEFT OUTER JOIN
      SalesData ON ItemMaster.BrandName = SalesData.Brand LEFT OUTER JOIN
      CustomerMaster ON SalesData.CustomerID = CustomerMaster.CustomerID
GROUP BY BrandName, Route, Division
```

Comment: the customer is available in customer master and we can count them because the customer has Route and division, if the brand has not been purchase by any customer the we can show zero. Please check

Comment: Then that is exactly what you get with the second query. It show's a zero customer count because the brand is zero?

Comment: The problem is I don't have the count of Available customer per division and Route

Comment: What is the definition of an available customer?

Comment: All customers in the customer master

Comment: Based on Brand to show avaiabale customer in the division and show how many of them has bought the brand. So for each Brand in item master there will be two division.

Comment: What I would suggest is if you create the result you want in an excel spreadsheet and update your question with that. That way I can see exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using your sqlfiddle data there are 25 sales records & 18 distinct brand/ division/ route/ customer records and there are no sales invloving 100PLUS

```
select
        B.BrandName
      , V.Division
      , coalesce(Brand_count,0) as Brand_count
      , coalesce(Division_count,0) as Division_count
from (select distinct BrandName from ItemMaster) as B
cross join (select distinct Division from CustomerMaster) as V
left join (
            select
                    Brand
                  , Division
                  , sum(cust_count) over (partition by Brand)    as Brand_count
                  , sum(cust_count) over (partition by Division) as Division_count
            from (
                  select
                          S.Brand
                        , C.Division
                        , count(distinct S.CustomerID) cust_count
                  from salesdata as S
                  inner join CustomerMaster as C
                                on S.CustomerID  = C.CustomerID
                  inner join ItemMaster as I
                                on S.item = I.ItemCode
                  group by
                          S.Brand
                        , C.Division
                  ) as S
          ) as D
                  on B.BrandName = D.Brand
                 and V.Division = D.Division
order by
        B.BrandName
      , V.Division
;
```

---

```
| BRANDNAME | DIVISION | BRAND_COUNT | DIVISION_COUNT |
|-----------|----------|-------------|----------------|
|   100PLUS |    Dubai |           0 |              0 |
|   100PLUS |      RAK |           0 |              0 |
|     KITCO |    Dubai |           9 |             11 |
|     KITCO |      RAK |           9 |              7 |
|  Red Bull |    Dubai |           9 |             11 |
|  Red Bull |      RAK |           9 |              7 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fecb0/27

Comment: I need to see all brands from item master, your result will show only the item that has sales

Comment: All you need is a list of all brands, then use that as your from "table" and then left join the query I proposed. You will end up with NULLS of course so I leave it to you to use ISNULL or COALESCE to solve those issues.

Comment: my friend the count of Brand is wrong it shows as null. you should count the customer using customer master and sales_count to show as zero

Comment: this is my problem, there is no different from my result and yours and my original issue remains the same. This is what I want to see [Link](https://ethercalc.org/mmnzizii2u)

Comment: Well the layout at that spreadsheet contains results that cannot be produced from the sample data at sqlfiddle. e.g. there isn't a single sale involving brand 100PLUS, so I don't know how to meet an expected result that has figures I simply cannot produce from the raw data provided. but I'll take another look, back soon.

Comment: the sample is not wrong I need 100Plus brand in the list and the sales_count should be zero for this brand. this is the challenge that I have

Comment: I did not say the sample data was wrong... I said there were no sales for 100Plus and, quote "so I leave it to you to use ISNULL or COALESCE to solve those issues". If you don't know how/when to use those functions then you will now see have also done that part also. Please note the result layout is similar to your spreadsheet, I assume you will change any headings to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

All Credit to @kevriley

```
select 
A.BrandName,
B.Division,
B.Route,
B.DivisionTotalCustomers,
B.RouteTotalCustomers,
isnull(C.PurchasedCustomersCount,0) as PurchasedCustomersCount
from 
(
select distinct
BrandName, Route, Division
from dbo.ItemMaster
cross join dbo.CustomerMaster
) A
join
(
select distinct
Division,
Route,
DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Division order by c.CustomerID asc) + DENSE_RANK() over                  (partition by Division order by c.CustomerID desc) - 1 as DivisionTotalCustomers   ,
DENSE_RANK() over (partition by ROUTE order by c.CustomerID asc) + DENSE_RANK() over     (partition by ROUTE order by c.CustomerID desc) - 1 as RouteTotalCustomers
from    CustomerMaster c
    left join SalesData s on c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
) B on B.Division = A.Division and B.Route = A.Route
left join
(
select 
   s.brand,
   c.division,
   c.route,
   PurchasedCustomersCount = count(distinct C.CustomerID)
 FROM CustomerMaster c 
 JOIN SalesData s on c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID 
 --join ItemMaster i on s.item = i.itemcode
GROUP by s.brand, c.division, c.route
) C on A.Brandname = C.Brand and C.Division = A.Division and C.Route = A.Route
```

See the same on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fecb0/28)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select B.Brandname,B.Division,C AS DivisionTotalCustomerCount,
ISNULL(T.Count,0) AS PURCHASEDCUSTOMERSCOUNT
from 
(
Select CM.Division,M.BrandName,COUNT(distinct CM.CustomerID) AS C
from dbo.CustomerMaster CM
CROSS JOIN ItemMaster M 
GROUP BY CM.Division,M.BrandName
)B
LEFT JOIN
(Select Division,Brand,COUNT(Distinct C.CustomerID) As Count from CustomerMaster C
JOIN salesdata D
On C.CustomerID=D.CustomerID
where D.Brand='Red Bull'
GROUP BY Division,Brand
)T
ON B.Brandname=T.Brand
and B.Division=T.Division
Order by 1,2
```